# Know a function name by its runtime address on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system

I am writing a C++ Qt application, and I try to profile it so I can see the slow functions in it.

I use Very sleepy CS in order to achieve that. But when in debug mode I get the function names and nice callstack information, I only get hexadecimal address and no callstack in release mode, but performance profiling should be done in release mode because debug mode does a lot of stuff (it's already 8/10 times faster just by switching mode ^^).

I've try to generate a .map file but, it seems that the offset present in the file only contains information about the address IN the .exe file (these informations are similar to those in a ELF file, but are outside the executable).

So I would like to know, is there a way to get the symbols name by their address at runtime (like if I get the start adress of the programm, the offsets will make sense, as it can be done with ELF file, get the stack start in /proc/pid/map file and offset with the symbols offset information)?

Or is it possible to generate a .pdb file without debug mode?

Comment: Hah! That's the bitter part. C++ compiler mangles your program and control flow in a way that any debug information might be useless. It might get rid of those functions and even entire classes. It might perform optimizations on link-time, erasing what was left. Remember: compiler does not produce the program you think you are writing, but a program that just behaves same way.

Comment: You can generate a PDB/symbols for a release binary in the same way as automatically happens for a dedug binary if thats what your asking ...

Comment: @AlexK. How? I set /MAP /ZI as flags but only get a .map file, if I set /debug I got my .pdb file but I'm not in realease mode anymore

Drop:  inlining is an exemple of ruining any debug information isn't it?

Comment: What ide/compiler are you using?

Comment: @AlexK. : Qt Creator / MSVC2013 64bit

Comment: Nope, [`/DEBUG` linker flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe4t6fc1.aspx) does not influence optimization. Yes, inlining washes away function boundaries and further instruction reordering makes it really hard to map instructions to the code fragments. Whole program optimization washes away module boundaries, so it's even hard to say in which .cpp file or library we are now. You might try a Visual Studio profiler, if it's more accurate than 3rd party tools. Otherwise take a look at the disassembly. There are also ways to suppress optimizations locally.